# How to remove duplicated rows by a column in an R matrix

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicated rows by one column (e.g the 1st column) in an R matrix. How can I extract the unique set by one column from a matrix? I've used

```
x_1 <- x[unique(x[,1]),]
```

While the size is correct, all of the values are `NA`. So instead, I tried

```
x_1 <- x[-duplicated(x[,1]),]
```

But the dimensions were incorrect.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you're confused about how subsetting works in R. `unique(x[,1])` will return the set of unique values in the first column. If you then try to *subset* using those values R thinks you're referring to *rows* of the matrix. So you're likely getting NAs because the values refer to rows that don't exist in the matrix.

Your other attempt runs afoul of the fact that `duplicated` returns a *boolean* vector, not a vector of indices. So putting a minus sign in front of it converts it to a vector of 0's and -1's, which again R interprets as trying to refer to rows.

Try replacing the '-' with a '!' in front of `duplicated`, which is the boolean negation operator. Something like this:

```
m <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
m[c(2,5,9),1] <- 1
m[!duplicated(m[,1]),]
```

Answer (score 13):

As you need the indeces of the unique rows, use `duplicated` as you tried. The problem was using `-` instead of `!`, so try:

```
x[!duplicated(x[,1]),]
```