# how to remove unwanted rows according to filter results in R

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R but I met a problem in removing unwanted rows in R. So what I got is a file of species distrubtion data. I need to sort the whole dataset according to the XY coordinates, and project the data onto ArcGIS. The problem was that there are multiple entries of the same species on the same XY coordinates, so I have to remove the repeated rows on the same XY coordinates.

Here's a small example of how the data looks:

```
SpeciesID  X       Y
38         333500  96500
38         333500  96500
```

Here I need to keep the first row of the species with ID 38, but delete the second row.

Thanks

Jordan

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove duplicated rows by a column in a matrix in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835753/how-to-remove-duplicated-rows-by-a-column-in-a-matrix-in-r)

Comment: Also related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts

Answer (score 1):

> > [**unique**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/unique.html) returns a vector, data frame or array like **x** but with duplicate elements/rows removed.

```
> x = read.table(file='input.txt', header=TRUE)
> x
  SpeciesID      X     Y
1        38 333500 96500
2        38 333500 96500
> unique(x)
  SpeciesID      X     Y
1        38 333500 96500
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`unique()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html), e.g.:

```
> df <- data.frame(SpeciesID=c("38", "38"), X=c("333500", "333500"), Y=c("96500", "96500"))
> unique(df)
  SpeciesID      X     Y
1        38 333500 96500
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for `?duplicated` or `?unique`:

```
df <- data.frame();
df <- rbind(df, c(38,333500,96500))
df <- rbind(df, c(38,333500,96500))
colnames(df) <- c("SpeciesID", "X", "Y")

df[!duplicated(df$SpeciesID),]
```